# SpringBoot 2 transaction propagation NESTED not supported

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a SpringBoot 2 project and i'm using spring data jpa with hibernate with MySQL5.7

I have problems with the following use case: i have a service method that calls another service's method. If second service's method generates a runtime exception, also the first method is marked as rollback and i cannot commit things anymore. I'd like to only rollback second method and still commit something in the first one.

I tried to use propagation.NESTED but nested transaction are not allowed with hibernate (even if jpaTransactionManager supports them and MySQL supports savepoints).

How can i solve this problem? Can i configure nested in some way?

Please remember i need second method to see changes committed by first so i can't mark the second method as propagation.REQUIRES_NEW

Here is come sample code to clarify my problem:

FirstServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class FirstServiceImpl implements FirstService

@Autowired
SecondService secondService;

@Autowired
FirstServiceRepository firstServiceRepository;

@Transactional
public void firstServiceMethod() {
    //do something
    ...
    FirstEntity firstEntity = firstServiceRepository.findByXXX();
    firstEntity.setStatus(0);
    firstServiceRepository.saveAndFlush(firstEntity);
    ...
    boolean runtimeExceptionHappened = secondService.secondServiceMethod();
    if (runtimeExceptionHappened) {
        firstEntity.setStatus(1);
        firstServiceRepository.save();
    } else {
        firstEntity.setStatus(2);
        firstServiceRepository.save();
    }
}
```

SecondServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class SecondServiceImpl implements SecondService


@Transactional
public boolean secondServiceMethod() {
    boolean runtimeExceptionHappened = false;
    try {
    //do something that saves to db but that may throw a runtime exception
    ...
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        runtimeExceptionHappened = true;
    }
    return runtimeExceptionHappened;
}
```

So the problem is that when secondServiceMethod() raises a runtime exception it rollback its operations (and that's OK) and then set its return variable runtimeExceptionHappened to false, but then firstServiceMethod is marked as rollback only and then

```
firstEntity.setStatus(1);
firstServiceRepository.save();
```

isn't committed.

Since i can't use NESTED propagation how can i achieve my goal?

Comment: Use REQUIRED_NEW

Comment: @WilderValera as i wrote, "...Please remember i need second method to see changes committed by first so i can't mark the second method as propagation.REQUIRES_NEW...". REQUIRES_NEW on secondServiceMethod wouldn't see firstServiceMethod changes (i've edited code sample to stress that out)

Comment: Using REQUERIED_NEW in secondService should work. I looked at your code and it seems you can't commit anymore due saveAndFlush(firstEntity) this can mark your first tx as commited.

Comment: REQUIRES_NEW starts a new transaction so if the first one's commits aren't seen in the second since first hasn't still completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you break them up into two separate transactions.

In the first transaction do all of the work presently in `firstServiceMethod` that you know you want to commit. (e.g. through saveAndFlush). Now as you exit this method the changes are committed, so they will be available to subsequent calls.

Then have whatever called `firstServiceMethod` call a new Transactional method `setFirstEntityStatus()` that calls `secondServiceMethod` and sets the status of the entity as appropriate.

Basically, instead of attempting to NEST the transactions, split them into two fully separate transactions and use the ordering to ensure the result of the 1st is available to the 2nd.

Comment: Ok but that sounds like a workaround and forces me to move second service invocation on controller even if controller may not know detailed implementations of service

Comment: It is a workaround... a workaround for the fact that Nested Transactions are not supported :-)

Comment: I hoped there was a better way but seems that yours is the only feasible solution. I'll accept your answer even if i don't like extracting logic from the service.